# Windows Form Picturebox Button cycle

Tags: c#, winforms, indexing, picturebox

Here is my question and I did Google a lot is there any place or site or can anybody tell me how I can create a button in windows from that is attached to a picture box which every time I click on cycles though the pictures.

Ex: I click button, and it switches to the next picture etc.
I have an idea of using index or something but don't know how to carry it out.

Would appreciate if you could help me or  give me the resources to.

I tried this but it ain't working lol....

```
string[] picture = {
    @"ImageResource\Icon\1.jpg",
    @"ImageResource\Icon\2.jpg",
    @"ImageResource\Icon\3.jpg",
    @"ImageResource\Icon\4.jpg",
    @"ImageResource\Icon\5.jpg",
    @"ImageResource\Icon\6.jpg"
};
for (int timesClicked = 0; timesClicked < 6; timesClicked++)
{
    if (timesClicked == 0)
    {
        Image image = Image.FromFile("1.jpg"); pictureBox1.Image = image;
    }
    else if (timesClicked == 1)
    {
        Image image = Image.FromFile("2.jpg"); pictureBox1.Image = image;
    }
    else if (timesClicked == 2)
    {
        Image image = Image.FromFile("3.jpg"); pictureBox1.Image = image;
    }
    else if (timesClicked == 3)
    {
        Image image = Image.FromFile("4.jpg"); pictureBox1.Image = image;
    }
    else if (timesClicked == 4)
    {
        Image image = Image.FromFile("5.jpg"); pictureBox1.Image = image;
    }
    else if (timesClicked == 5)
    {
        Image image = Image.FromFile("6.jpg"); pictureBox1.Image = image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use picture box to display image.

```
Image image = Image.FromFile("FileName.png");
pictureBox1.Image = image;
```

Create a list of string containing all file names of pictures.

set a  variable as `int index = 0;`
on button click increment this index and change Image source from list by using index.
when `index == list.Count` then set `index = 0;`